# Why has a question's post notice been added to an answer?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, answers, post-notice

I just noticed that [an answer](https://superuser.com/a/492301) has a post notice that says "we're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context...". Why would an answer have answers? It doesn't make sense to me. In other words, why was a post notice that is normally added to a question added to an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That post notice was added at the same time that a moderator added a comment asking for more clarification (which was subsequently added). The post notice can be used as a way of asking the user to expand their answer.

Generally, a post notice like that should be removed from an *answer* once an edit has been applied, or is more appropriate as a comment to begin with. I've removed the post notice since it's unnecessary now.

Comment: Yup, I forgot to check up on that, my bad.